# How to create a generic method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method:

```
public static void update(String name) {
    CustomTextType obj = findByName(name);
    ...
}
```

I'd like to make it a general use method so that I don't need to write new code for every new custom type.  I could do this, which would require instantiating the object before calling update():

```
public static void update(String name, Object obj) {
    obj = findByName(name);
    ...
}
```

Out of curiosity, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using Java Generics:

```
// note: this is an example and does not work
public static void update(String name, <T> type) {
    type var = findByName(name);
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Java?

Comment: if they have something in common then yes.. but you have to see what returns `findByName()`

Comment: Generic methods look like this.

    Yes java generics are really simple
like this

    public static <T extends Object> void name(T obj){
  
 }

Comment: Your example makes no sense. Why would you take an `Object` parameter only to reassign it with `obj = findByName(name);` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
public static <T> void update(String name, T type) {
    //logic dealing with `T`.
}
```

Note that `T` will be reifiable in this case. Either `Foo<T>`(which itself includes `Class<T>` that can be obtained from `instanceOfT.getClass()`) or `T` itself has been passed in.

Comment: method is not "returning T" (`void`)

Comment: @RC. Sorry, got this confused with another post I wrong about generics.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I find I still need to write "static <T> void", otherwise 'T' can't be resolved.  Am I misunderstanding the comment above?  Also, what does the call to this method look like?

Comment: @TERACytE Yes, you still must write `static <T> void`. You'll call it as such: `update("foo", someObject)`. No need tor tricky syntax to call it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I'm not sure what the advantage of this is over "void update (String name, Object obj)" though, since I am not returning the same type.  It appears that I need to create "someObject" anyway when using the above example (e.g. update("foo", new CustomTextType()) ).  Correct?

Comment: @TERACytE Yeah, there's no advantage to using a generic method here.